# Apache POI 3.12 compatibility with both excel 2003 and 2013

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to use apache poi 3.12 to generate excel sheets . I have used XSSFWorkbook and other corresponding classes to create the excel sheet however I am saving it with xls extension which is giving some errors while opening the generated excel sheet. I am aware of the fact that the so generated excel should be saved with xlsx as I am using XSSFWorkbook . The main problem is that the generated excel should be compatible with excel 2003 aswell how do I generate excel file that is compatible with excel 2003 , 2007 and 2013?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the POI SS usermodel (that was introduced with 3.5), see http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html for further details.

Also if you only need compatibility with Excel 2003 upwards, you can store the files as `.xlsx`.